# Read the data of a single channel from a stereo wave file wave with 24-bit data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wave

I want to read the left and rigth channel.

```
 import wave
 origAudio = wave.open("6980.wav","r")
 frameRate = origAudio.getframerate()
 nChannels = origAudio.getnchannels()
 sampWidth = origAudio.getsampwidth()
 nbframe=origAudio.getnframes()
 da = np.fromstring(origAudio.readframes(48000), dtype=np.int16)
 origAudio.getparams()
```

the parametre

```
  (2, 3, 48000, 2883584, 'NONE', 'not compressed')
```

Now I want to separate left and right channel with wave file in 24 bit data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`wavio`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio), a small module that I wrote to read and write WAV files using numpy arrays.  In your case:

```
import wavio

wav = wavio.read("6980.wav")

# wav.data is the numpy array of samples.
# wav.rate is the sampling rate.
# wav.sampwidth is the sample width, in bytes.  For a 24 bit file,
# wav.sampwdith is 3.

left_channel = wav.data[:, 0]
right_channel = wav.data[:, 1]
```

[`wavio` is on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio), and the source is on github at https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio.

Comment: thanks it's working but it's coorect to modifier wave signed 24 bit in 16 bit

Answer (score 1):

The parameters tell you that you have 2 channels of data at 3 bytes per sample, at 48kHz.  So when you say `readframes(48000)` you get one second of frames which you should probably read into a slightly different data structure:

```
da = np.fromstring(origAudio.readframes(48000), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Now you should have 48000 * 2 * 3 bytes, i.e. `len(da)`.  To take only the first channel you'd do this:

```
chan1 = np.zeros(48000, np.uint32)
chan1bytes = chan1.view(np.uint8)
chan1bytes[0::4] = da[0::6]
chan1bytes[1::4] = da[1::6]
chan1bytes[2::4] = da[2::6]
```

That is, you make an array of integers, one per sample, and copy the appropriate bytes over from the source data (you could try copying directly from the result of `readframes()` and skip creating `da`).

Comment: Thanks @John Zwing I want to take the left and right channel data

Comment: @mouridetouba OK well then try the above solution.  If it works for the left channel you can do basically the same for the right channel, but using `da[3::6]`, `da[4::6]`, and `da[5::6]`.